# Can you update an asset once you've used it in other files?

Tags: asset, asset-browser

So I'm loving the asset browser in 3.0 but I have a question.

Say you've created a character, marked it as an asset and saved the Blend file in your designated asset folder. However, after employing it in a couple of other Blends, you go back to the original asset file and add, for example, a few new shape keys for facial expressions or replace a material with something better.

Can you update that asset in the new files you had used it in OR do you have to go back to square one and start over (eg deleting the character and adding the updated version)?

As I'm still quite new to Blender I may be missing something here but it seems to me that if you have to delete and start over then it's the same as appending a collection. If That's the case then, to me, that'd be a pity as I've done quite a bit of animation in the files I've used that asset in.

This same question had been asked a lot with older versions of Blender but I haven't seen it addressed with 3.0 yet.

Many thanks!

Comment: you can append the asset again, then use its mesh for example instead of the current mesh of the opened file, but maybe give more details

Answer (score 5):

The difference you're describing is between Appending and Linking assets. An appended asset comes in with its own unique data that is not connected to the source file. A linked asset has its data connected with the source file so that any changes to the asset in the source file are propagated to the file where it is used. The asset browser has a setting allowing you to choose whether you'd like to Append or Link your assets upon import. See https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/asset_browser.html#using-assets

Comment: Ahh okay. Thanks, @mcurt09. SO - in those files I've already created using that character asset, I need to go back to square one and reintroduce it as linked, rather than appended? There's no way to change that as an afterthought?